# How do you prove that the second largest number $Y_n$ shown among the first $n$ rolls is not a Markov Chain?

Tags: markov-chains

How do you prove that the second largest number $Y_n$ shown among the first $n$ rolls is not a Markov Chain?

> > My attempt:
> >     Consider the case, $P(Y_{n+1}=3|Y_n=1)=\frac{1}{6}$ if the current maximum is bigger than 3, but $P(Y_{n+1}=3|Y_n=1)=0$ if the current maximum is 2.
> >
> > So we require the additional information of knowing the current maximum.

But my tutor said we should explicitly come up with a concrete case where $Y_3$ depends on $Y_2$, $Y_1$ to violate the definition of Markov Chain.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: How is $Y_1$ defined? Just the value of the first throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $Y_1$ is defined to be just the value of the first throw. Let $X_i$ denote the outcome of the $i$'th throw. Then
$$
P(Y_3 = 3| Y_2 = 2, Y_1 = 3) = P(X_3 = 4,5,6) = \frac{2}{6},
$$
since $X_1 = 3$ and $X_2 = 2$. So to get the second highest number to be a 3, we need to throw a number higher than a three. However
$$
P(Y_3 = 3| Y_2 = 2, Y_1 = 4) = P(X_3 = 3) = \frac{1}{6},
$$
since $X_1 = 4$ and $X_2 = 2$. So to get the second highest number to be a 3, we need to throw exactly that three.

So $Y_3$ is dependent on $Y_1$ and thus $\{Y_n\}$ is not a Markov chain.

Answer (score 1):

First, with your definition, $Y_1$ is not defined. I will answer starting the chain at $Y_2$

If your "roll" is a heads or tail, calculate $P(Y_{n+1}=0|Y_{n}=0)$ and show that it depends of $n$